# Changing the Background color of GridView Row as per condition dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to change the color of gridview rows based on label value in a gridview. I have End Date value in the gridview, so i want to change background color if the End Date < Today's date.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gv_profile" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="300px" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" DataKeyNames="ID"  >

  <Columns>

    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="10px" HeaderText="ID" >
     <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="LblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID")%>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>


    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="50px" HeaderText="End Date">
      <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblEndDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("End_Date", "{0: yyyy-MM-dd}") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>

 </Columns>

  </asp:GridView>
```

code behind

```
  protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
         {

         }
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that should fit your needs

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && !((e.Row.RowState == (DataControlRowState.Edit | DataControlRowState.Alternate)) || (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)))
    {
        Label lblEndDate = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblEndDate");
        DateTime EndDate = DateTime.Parse(lblEndDate.Text);
        if (EndDate<DateTime.Today)
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.MistyRose;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: great :) you need to take care, not to colorize a header row or a row in edit mode - there should be a TextBox instead a Label and lblEndDate would be null - that's why i added the if-statement

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void grdView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "MouseEvents(this, event)");
            e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "MouseEvents(this, event)");


            if ((lblhidisinsert.Value == "1") )
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ecf8ec");
            }           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[1].Text);
        if (id > 0)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[1].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = Math.Abs(id).ToString();
            e.Row.Cells[1].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
```